# Python: short coordinate function unexpectedly changes incoming argument value

Tags: python, reference, arguments

The goal here is to take some list of coordinates, like `[[1,2],[3,4],[7,1]]`, then figure out how big the canvas should be if you want to print all these coords. Take the maximal bottom left coordinate and minimal upper right coordinate that will snugly fit a canvas to these points. In the above list, for example, we're looking for `[[1,1],[7,4]]`, which defines the smallest rectangle where all those points will fit.

In the middle of this function, I'm seeing the incoming "board" assigned a new value.

```
def print_board(board):
    # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    dimensions = None
    for i in board:
        if dimensions == None:
            dimensions = [i, i]
        else:
            dimensions[0][0] = min(dimensions[0][0], i[0])
            #'board' is redefined !!!
            dimensions[0][1] = min(dimensions[0][1], i[1]) 
            #dimensions[1][0] = max(dimensions[1][0], i[0])
            #dimensions[1][1] = max(dimensions[1][1], i[1])
    # (after we get the canvas size
    # we print the canvas with the points on it
    # but we never make it that far without an error)
```

As the for loop moves through the coordinates in the incoming `board`, it seems to be setting `board[0]` to whatever coordinate it's looking at at the time. So `[[1,2],[3,4],[7,1]]` will change first to `[[3,4],[3,4],[7,1]]`, then to `[[7,1],[3,4],[7,1]]`.

I wouldn't expect `board` to change at all.

(Python 3.2.2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
dimensions = [i, i]
```

you're setting both items in `dimensions` to the first point in your board -- not making copies of that point.

Then when you do

```
        dimensions[0][0] = min(dimensions[0][0], i[0])
        dimensions[0][1] = min(dimensions[0][1], i[1])
```

you're updating that same point --- the first point in your board -- to the results of the `min` functions.

Try something like this, instead:

```
def print_board(board):
    xs, ys = zip(*board) # separate out the x and y coordinates
    min_x, max_x = min(xs), max(xs) # find the mins and maxs
    min_y, max_y = min(ys), max(ys)
    dimensions = [[min_x, min_y], [max_x, max_y]] # make the dimensions array
```

Comment: I was suspecting it was a, not to butcher the terms, pass by value/pass by reference issue. Is there some way to, in a for statement, make a copy of the current state of the iterator?

what if I had done: 
dimensions = list(str([i,i])) (Hmm, if there is some way, that is NOT how...)

Comment: @Brownbat `dimensions = [i[:], i[:]]` would work. `[:]` makes a copy of a list. But I would recommend building `dimensions` _after_ you've found the mins and maxs, not before. This is Python, not C.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I guess you're saying it's not the for loop, but the list that makes copying hard... but for some reason, `mylist = [2,3]; i = mylist[0]; i = 3` doesn't seem to change mylist... even `for i in mylist:;x=i;x=3` doesn't set all of mylist to 3... there's still something here I don't understand... but you've given more than your fair share of feedback, so maybe I should just roll with it here and use intermediate values.

Answer (score 0):

As an extension of agfs answer, you can use [numpy](https://numpy.org/) for even more efficient and succinct code:

```
import numpy as np
def print_board(board):
    a = np.array(board)
    return [a.min(axis=0).tolist(), a.max(axis=0).tolist()]
```

If your board is a numpy array already, and you let the function return a tuple of numpy arrays, it shortens even more:

```
def print_board(board):
    return board.min(axis=0), board.max(axis=0)
```

Comment: While this is a good method, it has nothing to do with his question, which is why the board is being mutated, and so shouldn't really be posted as an answer.

Comment: @agf I see your point, but I disagree. See [this meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117222/157794). I think it fits nicely with this case, and the sentiment is to allow such answers. By saying I'm building on your answer, I make it clear that I'm suggesting an alternative, and I go on to say that it has to do with performance (ref. "why it's being suggested").

Comment: If his question had been "how do I use Python lists to do this" or "how do I use the `max` and `min` built-ins to do this", then this would be an alternate method, but he wasn't really looking for a method to solve the general problem, he wanted to know why the board was being mutated -- so the real question was about how names & mutable types work in Python.

Comment: If you read again, OP doesn't really ask any question, but poses a problem and points out an unexpected result. He starts out with: "_The goal here is to take some list of coordinates, like [[1,2],[3,4],[7,1]], then figure out how big the canvas should be if you want to print all these coords._". My answer is to provide a way to meet this goal. Of course I don't repeat your correct and sufficient explanation of why `board` changes. I suggest you create a post on meta if you feel strongly about this, so that the community can judge who is correct here.